# Animation on scroll. Animation is completed before I reach the element?

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to animate the box. It has to go from left to right once the scroll reaches the element!
The problem I am facing is that by the time I reached the element the animation is completed and I am not able to acheive on scroll animation.

here is my html

```
<script>
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        $('#box').each(function(){
        var imagePos = $(this).offset().top;

        var topOfWindow = $(window).scrollTop();
            if (imagePos < topOfWindow + 2000;) {
                $(this).addClass("slideDown");
            }
        });
    });
</script>



</head>

<body>
    <div id="box" class="slideDown"></div>


</body>
```

css code

```
html{
  height: 1800px;
}

#box{
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  background: red;
margin: auto;
margin-top: 800px;
visibility: visible ; 

}

.slideDown{
  animation-name: slideDown;
  -webkit-animation-name: slideDown;  

  animation-duration: 1s; 
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;

  animation-timing-function: ease;  
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;  

  display: block;          
}

@keyframes slideDown {
  0% {
    margin-left: -20%;
  }
  25%{
    margin-left: 20%;

  }
  75%{
    margin-left: 30%;
  }     
  100% {
    margin-left: 40%;
  }   
}

@-webkit-keyframes slideDown {
  0% {
    margin-left: -20%;
  }
  25%{
    margin-left: 20%;

  }
  75%{
    margin-left: 30%;
  }     
  100% {
    margin-left: 40%;
  }   
}
```

Comment: when scroll reaches the element.. you mean when you first see the element coming in at the bottom of the screen?

Comment: i think appear.js will help to stop animation till the .slideDown appear

Comment: Yes. Initially the box will be hidden. As soon as I reach the box element it should slide from left to right! @webkit

Comment: are you looking for something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/1979Lcz3/

Comment: Yes! That is what I was trying to achieve!I am a beginner can you please explain me your jquery code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way of doing it:

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1979Lcz3/)

What I did is use css transitions to animate between the 2 desired states of the element.. 1 state is stuck to right the other stuck to left..

## The js:

```
var imagePos;
var bottomOfWindow;

$(window).scroll(function() {
    bottomOfWindow = $(window).scrollTop()+$(window).height();
        $('#box').each(function(){
            imagePos = $(this).offset().top;
            if (imagePos <= bottomOfWindow-200) {
                $(this).addClass("slideDown");
            }
            else $(this).removeClass("slideDown");
        });
    });
```

explanation:

bottomOfWindow is calculating the bottom of the window of course.. the transition happends everytime the #box element comes into view plus 200px offset.

If you have any questions let me know.. good luck

Comment: Thanks a lot! You have helped with my problem! I am just confused by one term offset! Please help me in explaining term "offset"? I am not clear about that term!

Comment: @killerprince182 Sorry for the delay.. Offset in this case means, an additional amount over the initial calculation.. in other words, instead of starting the animation just as the element reaches the bottom of window, it waits until it's 200px over the bottom making the animation seem more naturally happening as the element comes into view.. you can play with that number to see the effect